# html5 video tag not working

Tags: html, video

I am working on a script called HOME (view it [here](http://webhaikal.github.io/Project-Home/%29))
Now i'm creating a video player and used html5 for it but it wont load the video. Its just black. Here is my code.

```
    <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
  controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264">
 <source src="/uploads/videos/1.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

Im using google chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research it seems that google chrome and firefox doesnt support mp4 videos but support other formats. So i will have to change the script to upload and maybe convert the video to other formats. [Source](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/client/how-to-embed-video-using-html5.html#fbid=G2nAiMtCoyZ)